# Induction of Restriction of a representation is the same representation?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I was studying Representation Theory and I am confused if the following is true.

If $H$ is a subgroup of a group $G$ and suppose $\rho$ and $\tau$ are their representations then

1. $\operatorname{Res}_H^G \operatorname{Ind}_H^G \rho=\rho$
2. $\operatorname{Ind}_H^G \operatorname{Res}_H^G \tau=\tau$

Are these true? Any hint how to prove them?

Comment: See the [Frobenius reciprocity theorem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Frobenius_reciprocity) for *finite-dimensional* $k$-representations $V$ over *finite* groups where $\operatorname{char} k \not\mid \dim V$.

Comment: If you try a few examples of induction and restriction, you will see that induction usually increases the dimension, and restriction always keeps the dimension the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, neither is true, in general. Restriction and induction are *adjoints*, not *inverses*.

For example, if $H$ is the subgroup of $G=GL_2(\mathbb F_p)$, then inducing and restricting a character $\chi$ from $H$ gives a direct sum of a whole bunch of characters. This is a feasible exercise.